# How to extract 2 integers from a char array C++ and storing them in 2 variables (Beginner)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

i managed to extract a line from a .txt document and store it in a char array

```
ifStream inData;
inData.open("test.txt');

char range1[40];
inData.getline(range1, 40);
```

The output i get is:

> BaseIdRange=0-8

I would like to store the numbers 0 and 8 in two different datatypes.
i.e. int1 = 0 and int2 = 8

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: First of all, stop torturing yourself with C-style strings. Read the line into an `std::string`, then put the line into an `std::stringstream`. You can use `std::getline()` to split the line into parts, and use `std::stoi()` to parse the integers. You can also directly split the line while you're reading it from `std::cin`, but that is less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that works for 2 unsigned-integers:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char buffer[32]{ "BaseIdRange=0-8" }; // Input line

    // Clean all chars that are not one of 0-9):
    std::string chars = "0123456789"; // 'unsigned int' legitimate chars
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        if (chars.find(buffer[i]) == std::string::npos) // I.e not one of 0-9
            buffer[i] = ' ';
    }

    std::stringstream ss(buffer);

    // Extract the 2 integers:
    unsigned int data[2]{ 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        ss >> data[i];
    }

    /* 
    // Or (instead of the last for):    
    unsigned int a = 0, b = 0;
    ss >> a;
    ss >> b;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

- It's possible to use `std::set<char> chars` instead of `std::string chars`, and to change the if line to `if (chars.find(buffer[i]) == chars.end())`, but I preferred to keep it simpler - the initialization of `std::set` is less-obvious.